# LookupRecord in SQL statement with WHERE clause does not work

Tags: sql, database, macros

**Background**
I am creating a database to tracks lab samples. I wish to put a restriction in place that prevents a technician from reporting multiple results for the same sample.

**Current strategy**
My query called qselReport lists all samples being reported.

```
SELECT tblResult.strSampleName, tblResult.ysnReport FROM tblResult WHERE (((tblResult.ysnReport)=True));
```

When a technician wishes to report a result for a given sample, I use a Before Change Event to check for that sample in qselReport (the code block below is my event macro N.B. it is not VBA).

```
If Updated("ysnReport") And Old.[ysnReport]=False Then
    Look Up A Record In qselReport
        Where Condition = [strSampleName]=[tblResult].[strSampleName]
        Alias
    RaiseError
        Error Number 1
        Error Description This sample is already being reported. 
End If
```

That all works fine and dandy. The error message pops up if a second result is selected to report for a sample.

**The problem**
I like to keep things as sleek as possible, so I don't want qselReport unless it's absolutely necessary. So I made a slight adjustment to the LookupRecord block so that it operates on a SQL statement rather than on the query. Here's what that looks like (again N.B. not VBA, just a macro):

```
If Updated("ysnReport") And Old.[ysnReport]=False Then
    Look Up A Record In SELECT tblResult.strSampleName, tblResult.ysnReport FROM tblResult WHERE [tblResult].[ysnReport]=True;
        Where Condition = [strSampleName]=[tblResult].[strSampleName]
        Alias
    RaiseError
        Error Number 1
        Error Description This sample is already being reported. 
End If
```

Now I get the error message every time that a result is reported, even if it's the first instance for that sample. From what I can tell, the issue is that the SQL statement WHERE clause does not filter the records to only those where ysnReport=True.

Can anyone explain why I can do LookupRecord in a query but not LookupRecord in an identical SQL statement? Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want things as sleek as possible, at least performance-wise, a stored query should, in principle, outperform dynamic SQL.

Syntax-wise, I'm not familiar with the macro constructs, but I'd consider enclosing the select statement in parentheses if it accepts them and also adding an explicit alias.  I suspect that alias would in turn need to be referenced in your WHERE condition:

```
   Where Condition = MySelect.[strSampleName]=[tblResult].[strSampleName]  
   Alias MySelect
```

Comment: Thanks @jjt for your suggestions but neither solved the issue. Regarding the parentheses, in the LookupRecord data block of my macro the In argument appears to be automatically formatted. No matter what sort of parentheses I add to the SQL statement, when I close and reopen the macro it defaults back to how it looks above. I also tried adding an alias and referencing it in the where condition but that didn't help.

Comment: @Dave - glad you got things working.  The elimination of Where clause redundancy certainly makes sense. I was going to try to spin up an Access Services db to debug but SP Central Admin console wasn't giving me much love on the config.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. The SQL statement where clause needed to be moved to the LookupRecord data block Where condition. This works:

```
If Updated("ysnReport") And Old.[ysnReport]=False Then
    Look Up A Record In SELECT tblResult.strSampleName, tblResult.ysnReport FROM tblResult;
    Where Condition = [ysnReport]=True And [strSampleName]=[tblResult].[strSampleName]
    Alias
RaiseError
    Error Number 1
    Error Description This sample is already being reported. 
End If
```